# Why does $\boldsymbol{\nabla} \times \textbf{E}=\textbf{0}$ imply $\boldsymbol{E_2}^{\parallel}=\boldsymbol{E_1}^{\parallel}$?

Tags: vector-analysis, rotations, electromagnetism

I am currently studying 'Introduction to Electromagnetism' by David Griffiths, and I was reading about the electric displacement $\boldsymbol{D}$. I decided to try to extract eq. 4.27, which states:

$\mathbf{D}_{\text {above }}^{\|}-\mathbf{D}_{\text {below }}^{\|}=\mathbf{P}_{\text {above }}^{\|}-\mathbf{P}_{\text {below }}^{\|}$

Where $\textbf{P}$ is the polarization.

To derive this I looked at eq. 4.25, which states:

$\nabla \times \mathbf{D}=\nabla \times \mathbf{P}$

And I know that:

$\nabla \times \mathbf{D}=\nabla \times \mathbf{P} \leftrightarrow \nabla \times \left(\mathbf{D}-\mathbf{P}\right)=\epsilon_0\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=0$

Now if $\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=0$ then $\boldsymbol{E_2}^{\parallel}=\boldsymbol{E_1}^{\parallel}$. If we consider the gaussian pillbox as a cylinder with height epsilon, then in the limit of epsilon$\rightarrow$0, we get that $\boldsymbol{E_2}$ is the electric field above and $\boldsymbol{E_1}$ is the electric field below. From this we get eq. 4.27; $\mathbf{D}_{\text{above}}^{\|}-\mathbf{D}_{\text{below}}^{\|}=\mathbf{P}_{\text{above}}^{\|}-\mathbf{P}_{\text{below}}^{\|}$

But my question is; why does $\nabla \times \mathbf{E}=0$ imply $\boldsymbol{E_2}^{\parallel}=\boldsymbol{E_1}^{\parallel}$?

Update: My understanding is that if the curl of the electric field is zero-vector, then electric field lines will propagate parallel next to each other through space. We consider the gaussian pillbox as a gaussian cylinder, where we denote the height of the cylinder as epsilon. In the limit of epsilon$\rightarrow$0, only the electric field directly above and under the cylinder remains. Since these field lines are parallel, we have that the parallel component of the electric field directly above is equal to the parallel component of the electric field directly belov, i.e. $\boldsymbol{E_2}^{\parallel}=\boldsymbol{E_1}^{\parallel}$. Perhaps someone can elaborate if this is a correct understanding?

Comment: What are $D$ and $P$? Above and below what? It would help if you defined your variables.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have given now defined D, P and the components E_1 and E_2.

Comment: I think you get it, but just to clarify: set up a rectangular curve perpendicular to the boundary. The edges that go through the boundary should have length $\epsilon$. In the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, those edges don't contribute to the line integral around the curve. But there is still a contribution from the parallel edges, which contribute $E_1^{||} \ell - E_2^{||} \ell$ where $\ell$ is the length of the side. Stokes's theorem tells us that if the curl is $0$, the line integral has to vanish, whence the result.

Comment: In making this argument formal, some care is required. You want to make $\epsilon$ small enough that the perpendicular edges have a negligible contribution to the line integral and $\ell$ small enough that $E^{||}$ is basically constant, but not too small, otherwise we can't neglect the perpendicular edges.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try to write this derivation on paper to get a better understanding.

Comment: It is not true in general. The tangential electric field across a double dipole layer is discontinuous.  See Section 1.4 in "Field Theory of Guided Waves," by Robert Collin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you are right, I also always thought of it that way.

You can also get something very similar with the divergence, for example knowing that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B}=0$ you can say that $\mathbf{B}^{\perp}_1 = \mathbf{B}^{\perp}_2$ with a very similar argument.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I was wondering what happens to the perpendicular component of the electric field if the curl of E is zero-vector. I assume that both of these will be zero-vector.

Comment: You can't say anything about the perpendicular component using the curl. However if you have that the plane separating the two regions has charge density $\rho = 0$ then you have $\nabla \cdot E = 0$ and so like in the example with the magnetic field in my answer you can conclude that the perpendicular in and out is the same (note that this means that the perpendicular component is "continuous" passing through the surface)

Comment: It is not true in general. The tangential electric field across a double dipole layer is discontinuous.  See Section 1.4 in "Field Theory of Guided Waves," by Robert Collin.